# ui-router controller not called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this controller to use some partials in my page with a form, but when i click to submit form no action from my controller happens!

ui-router config file:

```
$stateProvider
          .state('page-main', {
              url: "/page-main",
              controller: "PageCtrl",
              views: {
                "":  {templateUrl: "partials/page-main.html"},
                "header":{templateUrl: "partials/header.html"},
              }
          });
```

if i have the controller set directly in my view page, console shows an error of module include. As i have nothing appears!